# Assign variable to Animated.timing toValue

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to rotate a picture using Animated.timing but assigning a variable containing a number doesnt animate anything. Putting in int like 50, works.

`toValue: degree` does nothing, `toValue:50` does what I need. I print out degree inside Text block like it should.

I put animated.timing inside render() so that I can access degree const directly, I tried putting it in componentDidMount() but that just generated errors.

This code prints out x y z and calculated degree in xxx.xx format, I set up xyz in state and later use it to pass it to compassHeading function to calculate degree:

```
render() {
        const movementX = this.state.x;
        const movementY = this.state.y;
        const movementZ = this.state.z;
        const degree= compassHeading(movementX, movementY, movementZ).toFixed(2);
            
          Animated.timing(
              this.state.spinValue,
              {
                  toValue: degree,
                  duration: 3000,
                  easing: Easing.linear,
                  useNativeDriver: true
              }
          )
      .start();
    
    return (
        <View >
            <Animated.Image
                style={{
                    width: 350, height: 350,
                    transform: [{
                        rotate: this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [0, 360],
                            outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
                        }) }] }}
                source={require('./compass.png')}
            />
            <Text> {movementX}</Text>
            <Text> {movementY}</Text>
            <Text> {movementZ}</Text>
            <Text> {degree}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a new animation in every render and each animation will renders loads of time to vary this.state.spinValue for your animation and each render you start the animation again ...

You need to start the Animated.timing outside of the render function and depends on how often the movementXYZ change.(let say they change every 100ms) you may need to wait the animation finish, before you start another one. While it is animating, if any new movement coming in, store the latest value for the next animation. (I dont' suggest interrupting the on going animation too frequent, particularly using nativeDriver....so I let it finish one first.)

It look something like:

```
 onMovementChange(){
           const degree= compassHeading(movementX, movementY, movementZ).toFixed(2);                  
           if(!this.state.isAnimating){
                 this.setState({isAnimating:true,nextDegree:degree});
                 Animated.timing(
                  this.state.spinValue,
                  {
                      toValue: degree,
                      duration: 3000,
                      easing: Easing.linear,
                      useNativeDriver: true
                  }
                ).start(()=>{
                     if(this.state.nextDegree!=degree){
                        onMovementChange()
                     }
                    this.setState({isAnimating:false})
             });
           }else{
             if(this.state.nextDegree!=degree){
                  this.setState({nextDegree:degree});
             }                
           }
    }
    
    render() {
            const movementX = this.state.x;
            const movementY = this.state.y;
            const movementZ = this.state.z;    
        
        return (
            <View >
                <Animated.Image
                    style={{
                        width: 350, height: 350,
                        transform: [{
                            rotate: this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
                                inputRange: [0, 360],
                                outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
                            }) }] }}
                    source={require('./compass.png')}
                />
                <Text> {movementX}</Text>
                <Text> {movementY}</Text>
                <Text> {movementZ}</Text>
                <Text> {this.state.nextDegree}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
```